# Не меняется каталог в cmd с помощью команды cd

Tags: cmd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке видно что я пытаюсь менять директорию, пишу cd и директорию, но директория не меняется. Кто знает почему

Comment: смена диска делается так `E:\>C:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все дело в том, что по умолчанию команда `cd` работает путем смены каталога, а не диска.
Вы допустим пытаетесь из диска `E:/` перейти в диск `C:/`, это и есть смена диска.

Для решения этой задачи вам стоит заглянуть в документацию, хотя бы прописав `help cd` и вы увидите там:

> Параметр /D используется для одновременной смены
>   текущего диска и каталога.

Это собственно вам и нужно, команда в итоге станет такой:

```
cd /D C:\
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто ввести `c:` без команды. Это поменяет диск.