# cmd не переходит в нужную папку

Tags: cmd

Нужно перейти в папку (D:\python\python\course), ввожу "cd D:\python\python\course" и ничего не происходит, путь никак не изменился. То же самое с chdir.
Диалог с cmd:
`C:\Users\Пацу>cd D:\python\python\course
C:\Users\Пацу>chdir D:\python\python\course
C:\Users\Пацу>
Реально вообще решить?`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не меняется каталог в cmd с помощью команды cd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110799/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%b2-cmd-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-cd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда `cd` без параметра `/d` не меняет диск. Или до команды, или после выполните переход на диск `d:`, или используйте параметр.

Comment: Благодарю. Странно как-то, раньше получалось